# Adding way to get min number beside the max number

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the minimum number beside the max number, the issue is if I tried to make it in another if statement I get 0 on all numbers, is there a proper way to add a way to get min number ?

```c
int main() {
  int a, b, c, max = 0, min = 0;
  printf("Enter 3 numbers please : ");
  scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
  if (b > max) {
    max = b;
  }
  if (c > max) {
    max = c;
  }
  printf("Max Num is : %d \n", max);
  printf("Min Num is : %d \n", min);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `a` ? Should there be a `max = a;` somewhere?

Comment: _if I tried to make it in another if statement I get 0 on all numbers_. I'm not sure what you mean by that, could you show the code you tried?

Comment: Yes, you should initialise your `int min = INT_MAX;` or to some other very large number, which is at least as large as your expected maximum number.
Another approach is to initialise `int min = a, max = a;` after you have read the first input number to `a`.

Comment: usually the ```max``` is always initialized as lowest value possible and the ```min``` is supposed to be initialized as the highest value possible.

Comment: @RudrThakur Kind of true as you typically read values in a loop and don't save the individual values. But in this case it's not necessary as there are 3 variables.

Comment: Yes, obviously I was just pointing out the traditional approach, here he can simply assign them to any one of the three variables.

Comment: "I'm trying to find the minimum number .... I get 0 on all numbers". Try to find out when your `min` first gets that 0. You might be surprised and then smile and know where your mistake  is.

Comment: Welcome! When you get your code working, you can post it on our [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site to get comments on how you can improve it. Also, get a decent IDE. E.g Visual Studio Code, but any good one will do. Learn how to set breakpoints and examine the values of variables at various points in the code. Learning to use the debugger can prevent  many/most of the questions asked here. Goo luck & happy coding

Answer (score 0):

> is there a proper way to add a way to get min number ?

There are many ways to do it and it's opinion based which is the best.

But one criteria is that it's working correct. Currently your code isn't as it completely ignores `a`

To keep the coding style that is used in the question one could do:

```
  max = a;
  if (b > max) {
    max = b;
  }
  if (c > max) {
    max = c;
  }
  min = a;
  if (b < min) {
    min = b;
  }
  if (c < min) {
    min = c;
  }
```

Another way

```
  max = (a > b) ? a : b;
  max = (c > max) ? c : max;
  min = (a < b) ? a : b;
  min = (c < min) ? c : min;
```

or

```
  max = (a > b) ? a : b;
  if(c > max) max = c;
  min = (a < b) ? a : b;
  if(c < min) min = c;
```

or

```
  int max_int(int x, int y)
  {
      if (x > y) return x;
      return y;
  }

  int min_int(int x, int y)
  {
      if (x < y) return x;
      return y;
  }

  max = max_int(max_int(a, b), c);
  min = min_int(min_int(a, b), c);
```

or

```
#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

max = MAX(MAX(a, b), c);
min = MIN(MIN(a, b), c);
```

or .... many other ways.

You can also rewrite the program and use a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NUMBERS_TO_READ 3

int main(void )
{
    int number;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for (int i=0; i < NUMBERS_TO_READ; ++i)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) exit(1);
        if (number > max) max = number;
        if (number < min) min = number;
    }
    printf("Max Num is : %d \n", max);
    printf("Min Num is : %d \n", min);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising your `max` value, which is good, but in order to make it useful, you might need to initialise it to a more convenient value.
Therefore I'm thinking of the smallest value `max` can't even have. As `max` is an `int`, I'm thinking of `INT_MIN`, that value being defined in the already existing header file "limits.h", so your code becomes:

```
#include <limits.h>
max = INT_MIN;
...
```

For `min`, you might do the same, initialising to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Initialising `max` to `INT_MAX` is a real bad idea

Comment: Yep. Instead, it can be assigned to the first  value of inputs before comparison

Comment: @4386427: when I read your comment, I realised how stoopid my answer was indeed, so I have updated it.

Comment: @NeWi-SL: you're right. I just have the impression that the author is just learning about programming, which means: first initalising at zero, second initialising at a more convenient value, hence my (updated, oops) proposal.

Comment: as you  and @Yunnosch suggested your solution will work if the values are swapped at the initialization.Like,     `min=INT_MAX` and `max=INT_MIN` . I didn't give it a try but I guess it might work. Great idea

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach I can think of. It will save a little bit of memory space and provide a better experience to the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int max = 0, min = 0, tmp = 0;

  printf ("Enter 3 numbers please : \n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      printf ("%d:", (i + 1));
      scanf ("%d", &tmp);

      if(i==0)
        max = min = tmp;

      min = (tmp < min) ? tmp : min;
      max = (tmp > max) ? tmp : max;
  }
  printf ("Max Num is : %d \n", max);
  printf ("Min Num is : %d \n", min);

  return 0;
}
```

[Update]
I suggest it will be more convenient if you use the way suggested in Dominique's solution. Instead of below line,

```
      if(i==0)
        max = min = tmp;
```

Use it at the begining.

Comment: Sorry, there's been a mistake I'll correct it.

Comment: @4386427 I've corrected it  giving me the expected o/p's now. please see

Comment: @Yunnosch I think it's fixed now but I wouldn't do like this. The IMO better fix would be `int max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX`

Comment: @Yunnosch yep it did

Comment: There are other ways, arguably more elegant, but this should work now. (And I missed something when I wrote my previous comment. ..... Sorry.)

Comment: @Yunnosch No worries. I also tried what you suggested but then it gave me the INT_MAX and INT_MIN as min and max. But I learned something thanks to you.

Comment: Just for learning (not my favorite solution either) try to swap INT_MAX and INT_MIN for init values. I think you used the "winner" for init, you need to use the other one, the "loser". Double check the proposed code in 438s comment to me.

Comment: @Yunnosch ah yeah. a great idea to swap the values. I guess it would work